# installing plugin on wordpress local host i received fatal error

Tags: wordpress

Uncaught ArgumentCountError: 3 arguments are required, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-admin\includes\class-bulk-upgrader-skin.php:152 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-admin\includes\class-bulk-upgrader-skin.php(152): sprintf('%1$s installed ...', 'One Click Demo ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-content\themes\company-elite\vendors\tgm\class-tgm-plugin-activation.php(3553): Bulk_Upgrader_Skin->after('One Click Demo ...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-upgrader.php(813): TGMPA_Bulk_Installer_Skin->after() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-content\themes\company-elite\vendors\tgm\class-tgm-plugin-activation.php(3173): WP_Upgrader->run(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-content\themes\company-elite\vendors\tgm\class-tgm-plugin-activation.php(3286): TGMPA_Bulk_Installer->run(Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-content\themes\company-elite\vendors\tgm\class-tgm-plugin-activation.php(2892): TGMPA_Bulk_Installer->bulk_install(Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-content\themes\company-elite\vendors\tgm\class-tgm-plugin-activation.php(658): TGMPA_List_Table->process_bulk_actions() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287): TGM_Plugin_Activation->install_plugins_page('') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-includes\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-admin\admin.php(259): do_action('appearance_page...') #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-admin\themes.php(10): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #12 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\brandyukti\wp-admin\includes\class-bulk-upgrader-skin.php on line 152

Comment: Probably the plugin you tried to install is not maintained or is not compatible with your current WP version or theme.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I also have the same problem.

I try to get back to the 5.5.3 version of WordPress but the other issue has happened. Then it tells me that my site is not compatible with PHP 8.0 @@.

This's really amazing for me because I don't know when my PHP automatically update @@.

So the thing I do is downgrade to PHP 7.4 version and everything comeback work fine.

Let's try to with my way.

Cheers.

Comment: This answer looks more like a workaround than a solution. Probably better move it to comments.

Comment: Yep, I think we will have to contact the TGM author to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work with php@7.4 and found [this thread](https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation/issues/803#issuecomment-824762177) and as it said downloaded new code from [main repo](https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation) and now the error has gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Installing TGMPA will solve the issue in php 8. Checkout [TGM Plugin](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/installation/) and follow the installation instructions.